# How to read the number of lines in a multiline variable in Ansible

Tags: variables, parameters, count, ansible, multiline

I pass a multiline variable `dest_host` from Jenkins to Ansible as below

```
ansible-playbook -i allmwhosts.hosts action.yml -e '{ dest_host: myhost1
myhost2 }' --tags validate
```

In ansible i wish to count the number of lines present in `dest_host` which in this case is 2.

I can think of `command: "cat {{ dest_host }} | wc -l"` register the output and then print as a solution. However, is these a better way to get this in Ansible rather than going for a unix command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what the [`| length` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#length) is for

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: '{{ dest_host | length }}'
  vars:
    dest_host: "alpha\nbeta\n"
```

although be forewarned that your `-e` does not do what you think it does (about the lines) because of yaml's scalar folding

```sh
ansible -e '{ bob:
  alpha
  beta
}' -m debug -a var=bob -c local -i localhost, localhost
```

emits
`"bob": "alpha beta"`

but the `| length` can still help you by using `| split | length`

Comment: `{{ dest_host.split() | length }}` helped resolve the issue. Can you please update your answer ?

Comment: Do you mean that I should update the very last sentence, where it literally ends with the words "by using `| split | length`"?

Comment: yes @mdaniel as `{{ dest_host | split | length }}` errors and `{{ dest_host.split() | length }}` works

Comment: that's not my experience, otherwise I wouldn't have wrote it: `ansible -e '{bob: alpha beta }' -m debug -a msg='{{ bob | split | length }}' -c local -i localhost, localhost` -> `"msg": "2"` so I'd guess there is something broken about your system

Answer (score 1):

Do note that not all results may play nicely by just passing  `| split | length` — for example, take a `stdout` like below:

```yaml
stdout:
  - "this is the first line\nthis is the second line"
```

If you wanted to count the number of lines, `{{ stdout[0] | split | length }}` would give you something like 9 or 10, not `2` — it splits by spaces!

So, in a case like this, you would instead need to use `{{ stdout[0].split('\n') | length }}` (thanks Python), which would give you `2` as intended/desired.

Comment: Or `"{{ stdout[0] | split('\n') | length }}"` if you want to use the Ansible additional Jinja filter.